# Div сдвигается при масштабировании экрана

Tags: html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать что бы div не сдвигался при масштабировании экрана.

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
  position: relative;
  top: 83px;
  left: 163px;
  background: white;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://www.doylecollection.com/var/doyle/storage/images/media/doyle-redesign/images/blog/westbury/dublin-coffee-image-1/104529-1-eng-US/dublin-coffee-image-1.png">
<div></div>
```

Comment: Он не сдвигается

Comment: @Vearo нажмите развернуть фрагмент и смените масштаб

Answer (score 0):

Он не сдвигается. Может, наоборот, нужно, чтобы он сдвигался при уменьшении размеров экрана? Тогда нужно поменять px в top и left на какие-нибудь относительные величины вроде vw vh или процентов.

Comment: Нажмите на развернуть фрагмент и смените масштаб страницы, div съедет

Answer (score 0):

там у вас margin есть у body, надо убрать его и не будет скролла, также надо всегда писать box-sizing: border-box;